# Embedding a font into CSS, but the font does not show up in html file

Tags: html, css, font-embedding

A bit confused on the process here, but I've tried to embed a new font into a CSS file for an html website, but no matter what I try, the font does not appear on the html site. I've put the font through a converter and then put that entire file into my CSS folder that is in the same file as my index.html, to no avail. Here is the code I've put into CSS:

```
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    src: url('Montserrat-SemiBold.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('Montserrat-SemiBold.woff') format('woff'),
        url('Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: normal;
    font-display: swap;
```

Is there anything I can try to get the code to display properly?

Answer (score 0):

You should add the @font-face keyword to import a font
[See this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

Comment: Thanks for the input, however, when added, the font still does not appear in the html file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Start here:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

## hello world example

[image]

You should add a [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) (select element(s)) `body` for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'hello-font';
            font-weight: 600;
            /* Use chrome inspect and check if the path is correct */
            src: url(hello-font.woff2) format('woff2');
        }
        /* missing in your styles */
        body {
            font-family: 'hello-font', sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Your Website</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

#### "file not found"

Anyway if you use local files - no way to know if the path/filename is correct **without** live URL (Chrome inspect for `red` errors) - Error example:

[image]

### Option 2 (Better) - Load google fonts by CDN

** Better speed performance / Easier to maintain.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine">
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: 'Tangerine', serif;
        font-size: 48px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Making the Web Beautiful!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

- https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Montserrat
- https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started
- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font_google.asp

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out! I appreciate the options and the explanations, it was very helpful.

Comment: Great :) if the answer solve your problem please mark the answer as "solution". Thanks!